# How to make xarray dataset

Tags: python, python-xarray

I am attempting to adapt the [xarray Dataset tutorial](https://xarray.pydata.org/en/stable/generated/xarray.Dataset.html) to my data, but I am unable to get it working; I keep getting the error:

> ValueError: Could not convert tuple of form (dims, data[, attrs, encoding]):

Here is the code I am using to try to create the dataset:

```
import numpy as np
import xarray as xr

# xarray tutorial dataset
a_ds = xr.tutorial.open_dataset("air_temperature").isel(time=0)
print(a_ds)

# my dataset
lat = np.array([32.7847, 32.73563, 35.89973, 34.29235, 35.89155, 33.4852, 33.83317, 35.31416, 35.37686, 34.26979])
lon = np.array([-118.29, -117.9793, -117.77, -117.81, -117.5646, -119.14645, -117.317, -119.81319, -116.64825, -116.96787])
z = np.array([12, 13.44, 2.44445, 5, 24.5, 230.1, 33, 23.4, 1.76668, 9.3])

ds = xr.Dataset(
    data_vars=dict(
        temperature=(["x", "y"], z),
    ),
    coords=dict(
        lon=(["x", "y"], lon),
        lat=(["x", "y"], lat),
    ),
)
print(ds)
```

Does anyone know how I can correctly create the xarray dataset?

Comment: Because you have two dimensions - x, y, your z, lon, lat arrays need to be 2D, too

Comment: @creanion Would you mind explaining a bit more? I'm a newbie, so I'm not quite sure how to make my z, lon, lat arrays to be 2D.

Comment: `z` is your data, your mapped temperature. It has to be 2D, of shape `len(lat)xlen(lon)`, which is not the case.

Comment: following up on this - if z is *not* 2D data, but is a data series collected at a set of (x, y) points, then you could do something like `data_vars=dict(temperature=(['point'], z)), coords=dict(lon=(['point'], lon), lat=(['point'], lat))`, as the data is not indexed by x, y but by the point index.

Comment: @holycow - you could do .reshape(1, 2) on your arrays, where 1 and 2 are the respective lengths in each dimension. However after looking at your lat/lon data, they don't look like they are in a grid(?), so I'd go with what Michael says

Comment: If you look into http://xarray.pydata.org/en/stable/user-guide/data-structures.html I think you should treat your lat, lon as non-dimension *coordinates*.